# C# Give temporary read / write access to folder

Tags: c#, datastore

I have been tasked with creating a Windows forms application to handle information generated by people within my company, their information is parsed into a file and then stored in a shared location. Only me and a couple others have access to this folder in a shared drive however this brings up the issue of the user not being able to submit or retrieve files from this location on a machine that does not have my credentials.

The issue with giving everybody access to this file is that employees should not be able to see data or files submit by any other employee with the exception of administrator personnel.

What would be the best way to tackle this issue?
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Would a solution be receptive to architecture changes? Getting this off of the filesystem and into a simple Razor site would have a lot of advantages.

Comment: What about user impersonation? that would give you the ability to have other people access the folder. Another way would be to edit the permissions from your winforms app

Comment: Some service other than the Forms app needs to save the file. The app could post to an API on a server that receives the data and stores the file. The API app has permission to save the file. That also abstracts how the file is saved. Today it's a file. Tomorrow it could be a database record or something else. The client app doesn't care because it's not saving the file - it's just posting to an API.

Comment: Going a step further - if you give clients an app that includes code to grant permissions, they can decompile that code and find the part that grants them permissions. You can't safely give users the ability to grant themselves permissions.

Comment: Just a thought: You could run an FTP server on the folder, give users permission to subfolders.. They can then add the FTP site through windows and it would appear as another folder. Caveats is that normal "Save As" functions won't work. only drag and drop

Comment: Thanks a lot guys those are some fantastic suggestions, I think the web API sounds the most practical for my needs and business architecture. Could even validate requests to the API for each file to adhere to some additional company policies. Thank you all :)